# How to resolve nested if then statements resulting from using the conditional identity.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

If I want to turn the "p or q" part of an "if p or q then r" statement into an if then statement using the conditional identity then how do I resolve the nested if then statement that results from that. It seems like it would literally become if if p then q then r. Does that become if p then q and r?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Keep it simple, _if p then r; if q then r;_ but, what was wrong with "p or q"?

Comment: $(p \vee q) \to r \equiv (\neg p \to q) \to r \equiv \neg r \to (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$

Comment: @m-stgt Wouldn't that result in r twice if p and q are both true?

Comment: @SineOfTheTimes -- Yes, sure, but I regarded $r$ rather as a flag, something like $r=.true$, where it does not matter if $r$ was already true or not when executing the _if q then r_ clause.